# Sharing ssh-agent forwarded credentials across users with Vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant, credentials

I'm creating a VM with Vagrant and using the 'config.ssh.forward_agent = true' setting to forward SSH credentials from my host OS, but I'm struggling to figure out how to share credentials across user accounts. The default 'vagrant' account has the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment var pointing to a socket file under /tmp/ssh* that gets dynamically generated/named. If I ssh into that account and use setfacl to give my 'foobar' user rwx perms to the file, then I switch to my 'foobar' account and manually set my SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable to point to the same socket file, then everything works. But that seems like a really hacky approach and I can't think of a clean way to that automatically during provisioning. Ideas on how I can accomplish this correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you usever Sudo then you can configure Sudo to keep the auth sock var and every thing works fine.

Comment: I want to be able to login to the guest VM with different accounts (not root/vagrant) and use my SSH credentials from the host OS without sudo.

Comment: If I undestand correct you want to ssh inside of the vagrant host to the same  vagrant host with different users. In this case it's enough to set "  ForwardAgent yes" within `~/.ssh/config` for every user.

Comment: So I'm logged into the host machine as user "foo". I use vagrant to create a guest machine with a user "vagrant". The Vagrantfile setting enables "foo" credentials to be shared with "vagrant" on the guest machine. I want to create another user "bar" on the guest machine and also share "foo" credentials from the host machine with "bar" on the guest machine.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to run `ssh-agent` on your host machine (say `hostm`). Maybe this does vagrant for you. You can do it manualy via `eval ssh-agent` within your profile for example or directly in your current shell.

`config.ssh.forward_agent` within your vagrantfile has to be `true`.

All users within your guest machine (say `vagrant.box`) need to have the public key from the user "foo" within their `authorized_keys` file (ensure directory and file permissions!).

All users on `vagrant.box` need to have set `ForwardAgent yes` within their `~/.ssh/config`.

At last you have to add your private key to ssh agent on `hostm` via `ssh-add what_ever_your_private_key_is` on `hostm`.

Then you should be able to log into `vagrant.box` from your `hostm` via `ssh vagrant@vargrant.box` and from there `ssh bar@vargrant.box`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this gets me where I wanna go. I don't want to ssh into the 'vagrant' account on the guest VM and then ssh into my 'bar' account from there; I just want to ssh directly into 'bar' and then be able to ssh into the same places that I can from my 'foo' account on the host (eg. to be able to use GitHub, etc.).

Comment: It's the same. That's the way an agent works. You only have to add the right keys to the agent.